# Send parameters to shortcode taken from html select [wordpress]

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm new programming in wordpress and i would like to know if it is possible to take values of selects when the user press the button (html)and then send those values to create a custom shortcode like this:

[listing status= $var limit= $var2 columns= $var3]

It is like send parameters selected by the user dinamically.

Please guys, i've spend a whole day looking for this approach in google without any luck.

Help me!

Comment: I assume you mean for this to happen without resubmitting the page, and in that case no its not possible. The shortcode is implemented server-side, so its already done by the time your page is displayed in the browser.

Comment: @FlufflyKitten It does not matter if i have to reload the page.

Comment: In that case you can use a form to submit them and then get them in the via $_POST. Can you include the relevant code from your page so we can help?